# How to add a custom UIView as a loading screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, block, loading

I have tried to search and check many questions on this site but I still cannot find the answer for my question. Maybe there are some similar questions can solve my problem but I don't have enough experience to know about this, please forgive me.

I'm working on an application which using CloudKit to store the user data. So at the very beginning, when user access to my view, I try to get their userID by the method below:

```
- (void)initCloudKit{

_container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
_publicData = [_container publicCloudDatabase];
BOOL __block finished = false;

// get UserID and pass to self.userID

self.userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

[self.container fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
    if (error== nil) {
        NSLog(@"USER ID: %@", recordID.recordName);
        self.userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", recordID.recordName];
        finished = true;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"An error occured in %@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
    }
}];
while (!finished) {
    // NSLog(@"loading....");
    [self showLoadingScreen];
}
}
```

Everything work fine and as you can see, if the userID has't been returned yet, I will show "loading ..." by NSLog. But now I want to show to user a loading screen instead of showing this log to myself.
I have a method called `showLoadingScreen` to add a custom UIView during loading time but it's shown after everything is finished.

Note: I put this method inside `ViewDidLoad()` but somehow the log is printed ("loading...") at Launch screen ??

My expectation is: 
1 - Launch app with Launch Image appeared.
2 - My main view is show up.
3 - Loading screen will add to my main view during time I request the userID.
4 - Loading screen disappeared when I have userID (this will be easy so I have't include in the code below)

Please help me, my question is maybe stupid but I'm new and I still have a lot of thing to learn so feel free to ask me any question relate to this.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use while loop, it's hurt performance.

Just need showLoading when start load and when load end, you should hide it.

I have suggestion for you:

```
- (void)initCloudKit{
    _container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
    _publicData = [_container publicCloudDatabase];
    BOOL __block finished = false;

    // get UserID and pass to self.userID

    [self showLoadingScreen];
    self.userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

    [self.container fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
        if (error== nil) {
            NSLog(@"USER ID: %@", recordID.recordName);
            self.userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", recordID.recordName];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"An error occured in %@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
        }
        // After done, we'll hide loading screen.
        [self hideLoadingScreen];
    }];

    }
```

Comment: Exactly, the problem is `while` loop. The view cannot be shown until the while finish. Thank you so much.

Comment: But after changing, the loading screen is not removed immediately when I use `removeFromSuperView`. Do you know a reason? Removing UIView inside a block is a problem?

Comment: Removing UIVIew will not make any problems at all.

Comment: It's weird then. After calling `removeFromSuperView` method, it take around 2 or 3 seconds to be disappeared. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: Code is very simple, I have a method called `hideLoadingScreen`. Inside this method I only do a simple task is call: `[self.loadingScreen removeFromSuperView];`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do it once before this while statement, so your code may look like the following

```
- (void)initCloudKit{

_container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
_publicData = [_container publicCloudDatabase];
BOOL __block finished = false;

// get UserID and pass to self.userID

self.userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

[self.container fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
    if (error== nil) {
        NSLog(@"USER ID: %@", recordID.recordName);
        self.userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", recordID.recordName];
        finished = true;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"An error occured in %@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
    }
}];
[self showLoadingScreen];
while (!finished) {
    // NSLog(@"loading....");
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying help me. Actually I have tried this before but there is no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GCD(Grand Central Dispatch) to load the LoadingView when you are requesting the userID.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //loading the View
});
```

Comment: I also have tried this but it does not work. It's weird that even I put the InitIcloud method inside the ViewDidLoad but by putting NSLog, I can see that the log is printed out at the launch screen. How can it be happened?